# Angularjs and BootstrapUI - How to update variable in one modal based on changes in another

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui

There's an app using [Bootstrap Angular UI](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) with a variable `$scope.companies`. On clicking a button a first modal open where the companies from that variable are displayed in a `select` element.

The user may click **Add a new company** button to open a new, second, modal (on top of the existing one) where he may create a new company.

On closing that second modal the user returns to the first one, where however the companies in the select element are not updated with the new company that has just been created.

My question is - how to update the first modal so that it reflects the changes to `$scope.companies` and that new company is available in the select element?

In the main controller I use a factory('`sharedCompanies`) to retrieve the companies:

```
sharedCompanies.getCompanies().then(function(data){
     $scope.companies = data;
}
```

Than, every time when I open a new modal I do something like this passing the scope to it like this:

```
$scope.newCompany = function () {
    var newCompanyModalInstance = $uibModal.open({
        templateUrl: '/static/partials/newCompanyModal.html',
        controller: 'NewCompanyCtrl',
        size: 'lg',

        resolve: {
            events: function () {
                return $scope.events;
            },
        },
        scope: $scope
    });
```

In each modal I can access `$scope.companies` and they are displayed correctly. The new company is created successfully, however for it to be visible in the `select` element I need to close the modals and open them again...

How do I update the `$scope.companies` variable in those modals after a new element has been added?

Comment: how are you adding the new company?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comments! With your help I diagnosed the problem: I was not returning the right data from the modal! What had to be added was something line this in the second modal:

```
$http.post(addNewCompanyAndServicesApiURL, data)
        .then(function successCallback(response) {
            $scope.companies.push(response.data);
            $uibModalInstance.close({
                companies:$scope.companies,
            });
        }, function errorCallback(response){
            //...
        });
```

and this part in the first modal to catch the response from that second one:

```
newCompanyModalInstance.result.then(function (data) {
        $scope.companies = data.companies;
    });
```

That solved my problem! :)

Answer (score 0):

In the second modal after creating a new company before closing the second modal push the data of newly added company into `$scope.companies` using `$scope.companies.push(newlyCreatedCompany)`

Comment: That's what I already have in my code. What I was missing was how I have returned data from that modal to the previous scope! Thanks for your good suggestion!